# C# event handlers in G1ANT - correct syntax needed

Tags: c#, g1ant

I am enjoying using G1ANT's ability to embed C# code in my scripts. However, I haven't been able to successfully code event handlers that work. Below is G1ANT code for a basic form with buttons and an edit box - but with no event handlers. (Note I'm not championing the use of G1ANT for creating forms, but the buttons constitute a good example of raising events.) Can anyone provide G1ANT code to handle these button events (anything, just a MsgBox would be more than adequate)? By the way, I've tried modifying scripts that run successfully in [CS-Script](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script) , and programs that compile in VS 2019 and execute without complaint, but without luck.

```
addon core version 4.100.19170.929
addon language version 4.100.19170.929
♥macronamespaces = System, System.IO, System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing,System.ComponentModel
♥concatenated = ‴Donald Trump‴

⊂
   Form myForm = new Form();

   Button button1;
   Button button2;
   TextBox tb1;

   myForm.Height = 250;
   myForm.Width = 400;
   myForm.Text = "G1ANT FORM";

   button1 = new Button();
   button1.Size = new Size(80, 40);
   button1.Location = new Point(30, 30);
   button1.Text = "Click Me";

   button2 = new Button();
   button2.Size = new Size(80, 40);
   button2.Location = new Point(120, 30);
   button2.Text = "Font";

   tb1 = new TextBox();
   tb1.Size = new Size(920, 450);
   tb1.Top = button1.Bottom + 5;
   tb1.Left = 30;
   tb1.Multiline = true;
   tb1.Text = "Hello, Mr " + ♥concatenated + "!" + @"
   Didn't I just see you at the White House yesterday?
   ";

   myForm.Controls.Add(button1); 
   myForm.Controls.Add(button2);
   myForm.Controls.Add(tb1);

   myForm.Show()
```

The form looks like this.

Thanks in advance for all help,
burque505

[image: G1ANT FORM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adding event handlers in G1ANT is possible. Here's an example that will work for you:

```cs
   button1.Text = "Click Me";
   button1.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (Object o, EventArgs a) 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("test");  
   });
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you, Wiktoria! Just what I needed.